# Sharepoint search in library

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, modern-experience, pnp

We are using the PnP modern search web-parts but we get no results when searching on a one of our sites. Settings are OK, Searchable, Re-indexed, documents are primary versions.

On other sites (same tenant) the web-parts are doing it great.

What can be the problem?

Comment: When you created the documents? The data is crawled properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've verified that the data has been properly crawled without issue... I actually had this same problem on my 2016 Enterprise environment. There was no reason, that I could see, why information was not populating. It was only happening in specific site collections, even though they were created identically. All of my data was crawling and, in theory, searchable. I ended up having to delete the site collection and recreate and then it worked without any problem. Worst case scenario, this may work for you.